# Hive on Spark infinite connections

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Im trying to run a simple query on a column with only 10 rows:

```
select MAX(Column3) from table;
```

However the spark application runs infinitely with the following message:

```
> 2017-05-10T16:23:40,397 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0]
> ipc.Client: IPC Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from
> ubuntu sending #1841 2017-05-10T16:23:40,397 DEBUG [IPC Client
> (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu] ipc.Client: IPC
> Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu got value
> #1841 2017-05-10T16:23:40,397 DEBUG [main] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getApplicationReport took 0ms 2017-05-10T16:23:41,397 DEBUG
> [main] security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:ubuntu
> (auth:SIMPLE)
> from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:323)
> 2017-05-10T16:23:41,398 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0]
> ipc.Client: IPC Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from
> ubuntu sending #1842 2017-05-10T16:23:41,398 DEBUG [IPC Client
> (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu] ipc.Client: IPC
> Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu got value
> #1842 2017-05-10T16:23:41,398 DEBUG [main] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getApplicationReport took 1ms 2017-05-10T16:23:41,399 DEBUG
> [main] security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:ubuntu
> (auth:SIMPLE)
> from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:323)
> 2017-05-10T16:23:41,399 DEBUG [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0]
> ipc.Client: IPC Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from
> ubuntu sending #1843 2017-05-10T16:23:41,399 DEBUG [IPC Client
> (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu] ipc.Client: IPC
> Client (1360312263) connection to /0.0.0.0:8032 from ubuntu got value
> #1843 2017-05-10T16:23:41,399 DEBUG [main] ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getApplicationReport took 0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to an unhealthy node, therefore it was not able to assign the task. The solution was to increase the yarn maximum disk utilization percentage in yarn-site.xml because my disk was at 97% used :

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
        <value>99</value>
</property>
```